# Out of sample prediction

Tags: prediction, out-of-sample

I have a model in which I estimate the impact of price on acreage. My data is composed of 10 years. So I use these 10 years to estimate the model and get to coefficients. In next step, I want to use the model to predict the acreage for the 11th year. To do this, I have assumed that price in the 11th year equals to half of the minimum observed price in the past 10 years (which I had in my data). Now I expect that if I do out of sample prediction, since the price in the 11th year is lower than all of the observed price, the predicted acreage in the 11th year also be lower than all of the observed acreage? Is this correct? I am not getting this and am trying to figure out if there is a problem somewhere or my expectation is wrong?

Here is more explanation about the estimation method and the data: First I should mention that there are some problems in this estimation. For example number of instruments are greater than number of groups. But these result is the best result that I could get regarding my data. I am only interested in the sign and magnitude of the coefficients here and want ti use them to predict acreage. 
I have a data set over a period 2008-2017. I estimated a GMM model based on this time period to obtain own and cross acreage and price elasticies. The dependent variable is the log of the acreage of the crop. In the next step, I need to predict the log of the acreage for year 2018. To do this I used the average of the value of each variable during 2008-2017 for the year that I need to predict the log of acreage except price. For the price I used the half of the minimum of the observed price during 2008-2017. In this case I am trying to simulate a shock in the economy that drops the price of the crop. I used the following command:

```
generate logacr=log(acr)
generate logacrl=log(acrl)
generate logpl=log(pl)
generate logpi=log(pi)

xtabond2  logacr l.logacr l.logacrl logpl fui fzi logpi ppt pop  if year<11, 
gmm(logacr  logpi) iv(fui  fzi  ppt l.logacrl pop ) small robust
predict logacr_hat if year>10
gen exp_logacr_hat=exp(logacr_hat)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with Stata or GMM's. However, looking at your model, it says that there's a time variable `year` and it also mentions something about auto-regressive (AR) tests, so could the model have estimated something like a positive trend over time?

Comment: I figured out the problem. It is because of the other variables in the model as you also mentioned. Thank you very much.

Comment: No worries, happy modeling!

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a reprex of your data and give more information about the model you're using? It might help others solve your problem.

Assuming you're modeling your data with linear regression, and price is the only predictor of acreage, then you should be only getting lower predicted acreage if the estimated relationship between price and acreage is negative. However, if you have more predictors, it could be that some other predictors are countering the effect.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edited the question and added more explanation. And the coefficient of price is positive as I expected, that's why I think if price decreases, acreage also should decrease.